# md-chips when readonly='true', still need to have a placeholder

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-chip

I have the md-chips template as:

```
<md-chips dropdown ng-model="chipArray" readonly="true" 
 md-on-remove="blah($chip)" ng-click="blahBlah()" placeholder="Add an item"> 
       <md-chip-template><span>{{$chip.name}}</span>
</md-chip-template> </md-chips>
```

The md-chips is a dropdown in my case and I have my search inside the dropdown. Since readonly=true, the placeholders do not get displayed.

If I remove the readonly attribute, the placeholders are fine but I feel in cases as mine we would be still needing a placeholder. Or an alternative would be fine. I tried with container-hint which I am not sure is the right case here but it doesn't seem to work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWpaoB

First example is non-readonly and the second example is read-only

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your HTML for the following code:

```
<md-chips placeholder="Add an item" readonly="false" md-removable="false" ng-model="ctrl.contacts2"></md-chips>
```

The attribute `md-removable="false"` allow maintain your placeholder in your component, but this disables the possibility to remove your items.

Keep rocking!

Comment: No. I guess my question was misunderstood. My problem is I need a placeholder when readonly='true'. I cannot change my readonly attribute to false. If I change my readonly attribute to false, then the placeholder is displayed. But otherway, it doesn't

Comment: Because I don't want the md-chips field to be searchable. Instead I have a search box on a dropdown.